# Copy Batch Name and apply to duplicate folder

Tags: batch-file

I'm really sorry in advance.  I'm not a programmer at all, but was hoping you guys could help.  While using Google to search for an answer, this site comes up most in the listings.

I'm a photographer.  I shoot in RAW.  I have processed 100 images of spectacles and named them individually (according to their model and colour ref) and saved as Jpeg.  The customer wants them edited to a whiter background. I want to go back and edit the RAW files, but copy the Jpeg file names to the RAW files.  I hope this makes sense.  I can basically set up the folder structure to organise images by Date.  This will ensure that the RAW folder and Jpeg folder images are in sequence.  Then I just want to copy the file names.  Sounds easy huh?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to do this without resorting to DOS commands or using add-on software: In Windows 7 - Navigate to the folder in Windows Explorer. Select the files for which you want a file names list. Hold down the SHIFT key and RIGHT click on the selected files. You will see an option called 'Copy as path'.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, Irfan.  However, what do I do next? I'm trying to figure out if both of these suggestions are from you :P

I have manages to find my way to Copy as Path, and pasted the list in Notepad, but I don't actually understand the instructions below.

Answer (score 0):

on explorer, select all, shift + right click, copy as path. paste on notepad.

in command prompt, enter

hoge.cmd folder_path

```
(for %%1 in ("%~f1\*") do @echo %%1) > fullpath_hoge.txt
```

or drop folder on `hoge.cmd`

'`> fullpath_hoge.txt`' can be '`| clip.exe`'

or shortcut in sendto folder.

```
cmd.exe /c for /l %n in (1,1,2) do if %n==2 ((for %q in (%x%) do @for %r in ("%~q\*") do @echo %r)|clip.exe) else set x=
```